# how to kill the session cookie after a period of time in php

Tags: php, session, cookies

if I define the session.cookie_lifetime to be zero so the cookie will only be killed after the browser is closed. but if I want to sent a max time which after that even if the browser was not closed the session will end anyway???? integer

Answer (score 1):

This makes the cookie to be expired in one hour.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

More about setting cookie is at [here](http://php.net/setcookie).

Answer (score 0):

Normal Cookie
From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)
The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

That will give a nice long cookie.

Session Based Cookie
php.net link [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php]
For Session cookies use an int in seconds [360 = 6mins or 21600 = 6hours]

Also, for the session() cookie type make sure to add it before you start the session

```
$lifetime=600;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
```

Comment: what does this means?? that after 600 seconds if I sent another request from the same browser then it wont be from the same session??

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You could make it any number of seconds you want [*mostly*].  Also, because you are going to have the session_start(); at the top of each page when you are using a session, it will auto-update the seesion to make it 600seconds of inactivity.  You wanted to know how to change the session cookie lifetime variable at any time, outside the php.ini.  That's how.  :)

Comment: but do I must write the session_set_cookie_params($lifetime); at every php script. if I write it only in one php script and be there for the lifetime amount of time, will the cookie die?? and then when I go to another script that doesn't have the session_set_cookie_params($lifetime); but only session_start() will it start a session with a new id???

Answer (score 0):

Assign value for `session.cookie_lifetime` in PHP ini file.

`session.cookie_lifetime=300` for 5 mins

Comment: but will the cookie die automatically if I closed the browser before the 5 minutes has passed?